# Django::: paginator show all page of objects, how can i fix it

Tags: django, paginator

paginator shows:  first prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 next last 
how i can make it like this   « first‹ prev…2 3 4 5 **6** 7 8 9 10…next ›last »

i dont want to use django-paginator package also i tried django paginator tag but not sucess.

Views.py

```
def hire(request):

hire_article_list = hire_article.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0:200]
paginator = Paginator(hire_article_list, 2) # Show 25 contacts per page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    hire_article_s = paginator.page(page)

except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    hire_article_s = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.

    hire_article_s = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

#return render_to_response('hire/list.html', {"page_list": page_list})
context = {'hire_article_s': hire_article_s}
return render(request, 'hire/list.html', context)
```

list.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% for j in hire_article_s %}
{# Each "j" is a page_list  model object. #}
<li><a href="/hire/{{ j.slug }}-{{j.id}}">{{ j.hiring|capfirst}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
{% if hire_article_s.has_previous %}
<a href="?page=1">first</a>
<a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.previous_page_number }}">prev</a>
{% endif %}
{% for page in hire_article_s.paginator.page_range %}
{% ifequal page page.number %}
<!-- Do something special for this page -->love
<span id="currentpage">page</span>
{% else %}
<!-- All the other pages -->
{% endifequal %}
{% if page == hire_article_s.number %}
{{ page }}
{% else %}
<a href="/hire/?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if hire_article_s.has_next %}
<a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.next_page_number }}">next</a>
<a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.paginator.num_pages}}">last</a>
{% endif %}
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current page 6, you want to show `2 3 4 5 [6] 7 8 9 10`.

With the current page 5, you want to show `1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9`.

With the current page 10, you want to show `6 7 8 9 [10] 11 12 13 14`.

So, what is the law? The law is to show the current page number, and 4 smaller pages + 4 larger pages.

Given your current number *n*, you will want to show from *(n -  4)* to *(n - 1)*, and *(n + 1)* to *(n + 4)*

So, instead of doing:

`{% for page in hire_article_s.paginator.page_range %}`

You can do:

`{% for page in hire_article_s.paginator.page_range|page_filter:hire_article_s.number %}`

in which, `page_filter` is the filter you must define, so that it receives `page_range` list and `current_page_number` and return the list as above.

**Note**: Be careful with the corner case, when current page is near to the boundary. For example, if it is 2, you have to return 1 [2] 3 4 5 6, instead of -2 -1 0 1 [2] 3 4 5 6. You won't return the page <= 0, or > maximum.